# Blink an image on scroll

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My purpose is to make an image blink 3 times on a scroll (like lights on, then off, 3 times in a row with a 1 sec delay), then stay on until user scrolls down more that 3600px.

I've added event listener:

```
created() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollAnimation)
}
```

On scroll i fire method `scrollAnimation`:

```
methods: {
  scrollAnimation() {
    let currentPos = window.pageYOffset
    if (currentPos > 3000 && currentPos < 3600) {
      this.$refs.supportOff.style.display = 'none'
      this.$refs.supportOn.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
      this.$refs.supportOff.style.display = 'block'
      this.$refs.supportOn.style.display = 'none'
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the template for the images:

```
<div class="support__image-wrapper">
  <img ref="supportOff" class="support__image support__image_on" src="../../assets/images/247-off.png">
  <img ref="supportOn" class="support__image support__image_off" src="../../assets/images/247-on.png">
</div>
```

Now this code works, when i scroll 3000 pixels down, but not lower than 3600 pixels, it shows 247-on image and hides 247-off image. But, there's an issues with blinking it, if i will use `setInterval` it's going to be fired every time a user scrolls between 3000 and 3600 px. What's the best way to achieve that blinking?

Comment: Hi you could use the _intersection observer API_ to trigger your animation once your user has come to a specific point https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API
Or if it's a recurring situation in your app you could use the excellent _scrollmagic_ lib http://scrollmagic.io/

Comment: I've read it before, but due to poor browser support, i abandoned this idea. And could you explain, in case i missed something, how's it better than my approach?

Comment: There's a polyfill for the _intersection observer_ https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill
Also scroll based events which are not optimized/debounced can lead to serious performance issue, take a look at: https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/ https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/unnecessary-paints/#toc-scrolling
among many great resources online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to try...

1. Don't start manipulating the dom with `$ref`

Instead, create a variable which will trigger changes in the dom

```js
methods: {
  scrollAnimation() {
    this.showSupport = window.pageYOffset > 3000 && window.pageYOffset < 3600
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img v-if="showSupport" class="blink" src="../../assets/images/247-on.png">
  <img v-else src="../../assets/images/247-off.png">
</div>
```

2. **Blinking** I would advise using css animations (`@keyframes`). This way you can control the timing of the blink without anything in the script. It would just start blinking as soon as it's visible on the page.

```css
.blink {
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {opacity: 0}
    49%{opacity: 0}
    50% {opacity: 1}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: looks cleaner with a variable. But i'm stuck on how to do blinking with `@keyframes`, seems like there's a way to show animation once, or looped, but a certain times is not possible.

Comment: I've edited the answer. keyframes are actually quite versatile and there are a few ways you can make it blink. You can even stack multiple animations to play one after the other.

Comment: https://codepen.io/heihachi88/pen/exgXzd - it's blinking endlessly. How can i make it to blink just 3 times?

Comment: Just found it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add a quick demo for future readers, based on [t3__rry's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463123/blink-an-image-on-scroll#comment95734877_54463123) on how scroll based events which are not optimized/debounced can lead to serious performance issue; as well as [Mulhoon's nice advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54464543/3634538) on utilizing CSS `@keyframes` for blinking animation:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      blinkRate: 1000,
      blinkCount: 3,
      blinking: false,
      blinkTimeoutId: -1,

      state: false,
      currentPos: window.pageYOffset
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', _.debounce(() => {
      this.currentPos = window.pageYOffset;

      if (this.currentPos > 3000 && this.currentPos < 3600) {
        this.state = true;
      } 
      else {
        this.state = false;
      }
    }), 100);
  },

  methods: {
    blink() {
      if (this.blinkTimeoutId > -1) {
        clearTimeout(this.blinkTimeoutId);
      }

      this.blinking = true;

      this.blinkTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        this.blinking = false;

      }, 1000 * this.blinkCount);
    }
  },

  watch: {
    state() {
      this.blink();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  height: 2000vh;
  padding: 10px;
}

.page-offset {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.blinker > div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 35px;
  left: 20px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 35px;
}

.blinker.animate > div {
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

.blinker .on {
  background-color: green;
}

.blinker .off {
  background-color: crimson;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  49% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div :class="['blinker', { 'animate': blinking } ]">
    <div class="on" v-if="state">ON</div>
    <div class="off" v-else>OFF</div>
  </div>

  <code class="page-offset">pageYOffset: {{Math.floor(currentPos)}}</code>
</div>
```